# Marketing bollocks?

Tags: discussion

Today was odd for me. I asked a technical question about a motherboard but someguys down-voted me! Why? the question is this:

[4 Questions about Asus Z97 motherboard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118317/4-questions-about-asus-z97-motherboard)

I'm ciurios to know What's the mean of **marketing bollocks**???

Comment: I can clarify `Audio Shielding`: Our audio output was way too noisy to sell, so we put a piece of metal on something and it made it sound better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Marketing Bollocks" is probably the correct *answer* to your original question, not a statement *about your question.* Those are all terms that Asus made up to help them sell parts - they likely don't have technical merits or real-world impacts. It's like someone is selling milk and making the claim that "It comes from brown cows!". You can't disprove the statement, but you would be hard pressed to identify how the fact that "it comes from brown cows" impacts the milk that you buy.

Your question was probably downvoted and almost closed because it was on consumer electronics (a computer motherboard), and four questions lumped into one.

Comment: Thanks dear W5VO

Answer (score 2):

Marketing bollocks is a British (possibly nicer) way of saying **marketing bullshit**. If that translation doesn't help you, then you should understand that sales and marketing guys have a tendency to exaggerate, use hyperbole, mislead, or flat out lie about a products' capabilities.

The question you posted has since been deleted so I can't answer the first question. Downvotes can sometimes be a mystery to us all though.

Comment: Thanks friend for clarifying the subject. yeah, I deleted the question because I didn't want to get more down-vote.